# Ошибки во время INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

Вычитываю массив, в нем ориентировочно 3840 строк. Вот код

```
$insert = $this->DBH->prepare("INSERT into `sometable` VALUES(:id,:name_city,:city_ref)");

foreach($this->arrayCity['data'] AS $item_data)
{
    $insert->bindParam(':id', $item_data['CityID']);  
    $insert->bindParam(':name_city', $item_data['DescriptionRu']);  
    $insert->bindParam(':city_ref', $item_data['Ref']);
    $insert->execute();
}
```

Получаю одну такую ошибку :

> PDO::exec(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Получаю массу вот таких ошибок:

> PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away

Пробовал вот это:

```
SET session interactive_timeout=28800;
SET session wait_timeout=28800;
SET global max_allowed_packet=104857600;
```

Не помогает. Что делать?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74520/discussion-on-question-by-winteriscoming----insert).